# Why spring boot application constantly fetch configuration from config service?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I'm building microservices using Spring Boot & Spring Cloud Config. From the log file, I can see one of my application send a request to config service for configuration every five minutes while other applications do not play the same behaviour.

```
06:04:28.586 [serviceId:xxx-service/traceId:545d584f10da3123/spanId:545d584f10da3123/parentId:] INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment - Fetching config from server at : http://config-service
06:04:30.135 [serviceId:xxx-service/traceId:545d584f10da3123/spanId:545d584f10da3123/parentId:] INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.log - Located environment: name=xxxservice, profiles=[dev], label=master, version=00ed4aebcd466c88b4a7df61296652944642cdc8, state=null
06:09:30.367 [serviceId:xxx-service/traceId:519fdde3a2d8ce5a/spanId:519fdde3a2d8ce5a/parentId:] INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment - Fetching config from server at : http://config-service
06:09:31.928 [serviceId:xxx-service/traceId:519fdde3a2d8ce5a/spanId:519fdde3a2d8ce5a/parentId:] INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.log - Located environment: name=xxxservice, profiles=[dev], label=master, version=00ed4aebcd466c88b4a7df61296652944642cdc8, state=null
06:14:32.035 [serviceId:xxx-service/traceId:e32c45c3a5c3fcca/spanId:e32c45c3a5c3fcca/parentId:] INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment - Fetching config from server at : http://config-service
06:14:33.611 [serviceId:xxx-service/traceId:e32c45c3a5c3fcca/spanId:e32c45c3a5c3fcca/parentId:] INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.log - Located environment: name=xxxservice, profiles=[dev], label=master, version=00ed4aebcd466c88b4a7df61296652944642cdc8, state=null
06:19:32.033 [serviceId:xxx-service/traceId:16fc982b0638d4a6/spanId:16fc982b0638d4a6/parentId:] INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment - Fetching config from server at : http://config-service
06:19:33.495 [serviceId:xxx-service/traceId:16fc982b0638d4a6/spanId:16fc982b0638d4a6/parentId:] INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.log - Located environment: name=xxxservice, profiles=[dev], label=master, version=00ed4aebcd466c88b4a7df61296652944642cdc8, state=null
06:24:32.036 [serviceId:xxx-service/traceId:f4eae364e2624d58/spanId:f4eae364e2624d58/parentId:] INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment - Fetching config from server at : http://config-service
06:24:33.640 [serviceId:xxx-service/traceId:f4eae364e2624d58/spanId:f4eae364e2624d58/parentId:] INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.log - Located environment: name=xxxservice, profiles=[dev], label=master, version=00ed4aebcd466c88b4a7df61296652944642cdc8, state=null
```

I try to understand this behaviour.

### 1 Is the `bootstrap.yml` of this service distinct to other services, leads the unique behaviour?

No, all services `bootstrap.yml` appear to be the same structure without different config keys:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  cloud:
    config:
      name: xxxservice
      label: master
      uri: http://config-service
```

### 2 Is this servie trying to refresh its configuration dynamicly and periodly?

No, in order to dynamically refresh the configuration of a spring boot application, we need to:

- put the `@RefreshScope` annotation on the class reading configuration
- call with something like `curl -X POST http://xx:8080/refresh` to trigger refresh manually

So there should not be auto refresh behaviour periodly.

The question remaining unresolved, hope someone explain this situation directly or point any error in my statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you are not seeing this with other services, but I believe that this behavior is due to the client wanting to check the health of the server periodically.  From the Spring Cloud Config Client docs:

> 7.8.1 Health Indicator
>
> The Config Client supplies a Spring Boot Health Indicator that attempts to load configuration from the Config Server. The health
> indicator can be disabled by setting `health.config.enabled=false`.
> The response is also cached for performance reasons. The default cache
> time to live is 5 minutes. To change that value, set the
> health.config.time-to-live property (in milliseconds).

So just set `health.config.enabled=false`, and this behavior should stop.